# Curl page not working in tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, page-curl

I am referred the [Harism](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl) page curl to implement it in Action bar tabs.

Curl page working for Activity.Not for Action bar tabs.If I swipe the action bar tabs,the tabs wouldn't move.It just turn only one page.Because page curl supported only in activity.Not in Fragments.

Below I am posted the codes related to that.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private CurlView mCurlView;


    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Menu optionsMenu;
    private MenuItem menuItem;

    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

        int index = 0;
        if (getLastNonConfigurationInstance() != null) {
            index = (Integer) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
        }

        mCurlView = (CurlView) findViewById(R.id.curl);
        mCurlView.setPageProvider(new PageProvider());
        mCurlView.setSizeChangedObserver(new SizeChangedObserver());
        mCurlView.setCurrentIndex(index);
        mCurlView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF202830);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME
                | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mCurlView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mCurlView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance() {
        return mCurlView.getCurrentIndex();
    }

    /**
     * Bitmap provider.
     */
    private class PageProvider implements CurlView.PageProvider {

        // Bitmap resources.
        private int[] mBitmapIds = { R.layout.sample, R.layout.sample,
                R.layout.sample, R.layout.sample, R.layout.sample,
                R.layout.sample };

        @Override
        public int getPageCount() {
            return 5;
        }

        private Bitmap loadBitmap(int width, int height, int index) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            Log.d("index", String.valueOf(index));
            View v = inflater.inflate(mBitmapIds[index], null);
            v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
            v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(),
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
            v.draw(c);
            return b;
        }

        @Override
        public void updatePage(CurlPage page, int width, int height, int index) {

            switch (index) {
            // First case is image on front side, solid colored back.
            default:

                Bitmap front = loadBitmap(width, height, 0);
                page.setTexture(front, CurlPage.SIDE_FRONT);
                page.setColor(Color.rgb(180, 180, 180), CurlPage.SIDE_BACK);
                break;


            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * CurlView size changed observer.
     */
    private class SizeChangedObserver implements CurlView.SizeChangedObserver {
        @Override
        public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h) {
            if (w > h) {
                mCurlView.setViewMode(CurlView.SHOW_TWO_PAGES);
                mCurlView.setMargins(.1f, .05f, .1f, .05f);
            } else {
                mCurlView.setViewMode(CurlView.SHOW_ONE_PAGE);
                // mCurlView.setMargins(.1f, .1f, .1f, .1f);
            }
        }
    }

    }
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <info.androidhive.tabsswipe.adapter.CurlView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/curl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </info.androidhive.tabsswipe.adapter.CurlView>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

is it possible to do it in Action bar tabs(Fragment).I need some suggestion related to this.

Comment: hello,page curl is working for dynamic activities? I need activity wise page curl in android can you help me on this plz,

Comment: @User page curl is work for activities.Implement Harism page curl.I am not referred the code fully.just look out it.I think it will work in dynamic activities.

Comment: @User page curl will not work in Fragment

Comment: I have tried,but failed,can you plz help me on how to take dynamic activities for page curl?

Comment: Naruto,i have three activities,and how can i use page curl for activity by using Harism code,i have tried static layout page curl,it's working fine,but i want dynamic page curl.

Comment: @User I dont know how you used dynamic codes for activity page curl.Check out this [main activity](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/blob/master/src/fi/harism/curl/CurlActivity.java) and its [layout](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/blob/master/res/layout/main.xml).then implement it in a right way.

Comment: Naturo in that code static drawable paths are given right?is it possible to give the dynamic layout paths?

Comment: @User see that [stackoverflow post question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547301/page-curl-not-working-in-action-bar-tabs) I gave 3 fragment layouts there and fine only with activity not in fragment.

Comment: @User How many layouts were using to show page curl?

Comment: it's a dynamic, based on server request we are managing or creating layouts or pages,thats why i am strugling.

Comment: Now i have created one activity and 5 layouts,it's working fine for me.So same as dynamic layout i want.based on server response we are creating number of layouts(pages).